# String to argument name

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a ruby function (func) with named arguments (foo and bar) which I can call by providing either or both arguments like this:

```
func(foo: "whatever")
func(bar: "whatever")
func(foo: "whatever", bar: "whatever")
```

What I need is a way to call this function by passing strings for the arguments' names:

```
name = "foo"
func(name: "whatever")
```

I read about to_sym but don't know how to use it. At least this does not work:

```
name = "foo"
func(name.to_sym: "whatever")
```

Is there a way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func(name.to_sym => "whatever")
```

Seems to work in Ruby 3.1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
func("#{name}": "whatever")
```

The name will be interpolated and converted to symbol